# Eclipse IDE Problem When Open Project from one pc to another pc

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

Hi Currently we develop android pro In Eclipse, In Last Time I have problem when me and my friend try to open Project in one pc to another Problem is that

@override tag

when i override operation in class it did not problem but in another eclipse ide when try to 
open we required  to remove the override keyword.

so anyone can tell me what is this ,why we required to remove the override keyword in eclipse
ide

Comment: 7 questions.Didn't accept one?

Comment: Ok I try thank you for given help

Answer (score 0):

May be **`Project->clean`** helpful to you. Just do it and check.

Comment: No Sorry i try but not work Also Fixed Properties  but still not work i need to manually delete the @override  tag inside code

Answer (score 0):

Check the compiler settings for the project/workspace.  Depending on whether you're set to 1.5 or 1.6, overrides for methods from Interfaces are either required or forbidden.